# Pandas unable to select when '?' is contained in column

Tags: python, pandas

Declaring this dataframe :

```
columns = ['1','2']
data = np.array([['what is ?',2] , [1,5] , [2,3]])
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=columns)
df_1
```

Attempting to filter based on the value `1` does not return the matched row when a `?` is contained in column :

```
df_1[df_1['1'] == 1]
```

does not return any values

Appears `?` is causing the issue ?

How can filter when `?` is contained in the row being filtered on ?

Comment: The `dtype` has been coerced to `object` or `str` for instance `df_1[df_1['1'] == '1']` would work

Comment: You need `df_1[df_1['1'] == str(1)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your NumPy array stores your integers as strings:

```
data = np.array([['what is ?',2] , [1,5] , [2,3]])

print(data)

array([['what is ?', '2'],
       ['1', '5'],
       ['2', '3']], 
      dtype='<U9')
```

This spills over directly to Pandas:

```
print(type(df_1['1'].iloc[1]))

# str
```

There are a few workarounds, all expensive. If at all possible, it is advisable to have homogeneous types in your series. For numeric arrays, Pandas is able to hold data via NumPy in contiguous memory blocks. This yields performance and operational improvements.

#### Query using strings

Simply filter by `'1'` instead:

```
df_1[df_1['1'] == '1']
```

#### Convert integer types to int

You can convert individual elements of series to `int`. After all, an `object` series is just a collection of pointers.

```
df_1['1'] = df_1['1'].apply(lambda x: int(x) if x.isdigit() else x)

print(type(df_1['1'].iloc[1]))

<class 'int'>
```

#### Convert to numeric for querying

If you cannot remove non-numeric types from a series, when you perform a query you can use `pd.to_numeric`:

```
df_1[pd.to_numeric(df_1['1'], errors='coerce') == 1]
```